# How to pass json string with spaces to Python script using java?

Tags: java, python

I am trying to run Python script using java like below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class JsonToString {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("Query", "test projects");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(map);
        System.out.println("json:" + json);

        String scriptCmd = "python /Scripts/search_php.py \"" + json+"\"";
        System.out.println("scriptCmd:" + scriptCmd);

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(scriptCmd);
        System.out.println("process:" + p);
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("process wait completed");
        String line;
        BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        System.out.println("*******ERROR*******");
        while ((line = error.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        error.close();

        System.out.println("*******INPUT*******");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        input.close();

        System.out.println("*******OUTPUT*******");
        OutputStream outputStream = p.getOutputStream();
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
        printStream.println();
        printStream.flush();
        printStream.close();
    }
}
```

Python script is taking the value as below:

```
argv data :"{"Query":"test
```

Its ignoring the value after space.
Basically I have to pass the json string as argument to the python script.

```
{"Query":"test projects"}
```

To pass string with spaces (json string) as argument I have enclosed with double quotes and / to escape it also.
But I am not able to pass the exact string.
How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class, you can launch a process with an argument list, not just an argument string.  If you use this class, you can put the entire JSON string into a single argument, and access it directly on the Python side.

However, command line arguments can be somewhat limited in size.  (The limits vary from operating system to operating system and also depend on system configuration.)  It is likely more reliable to write the JSON data to the standard input of the Python process.  The `ProcessBuilder` class provides a mechanism for that as well.